# .cache/upstart/Unity7.log growing to consume the entire free disk space. Python cypto suspected

Tags: 16.04, unity, python, upstart

~/.cache/upstart/unity7.log is growing to consume the entire disk ~130GB in 7-10 hours.

If I tail the file I get:

```
xxxxx@xxxx-xxxxxxxx:~/.cache/upstart$ tail -f unity7.log
extern "Python": function Cryptography_rand_bytes() called, but @ffi.def_extern() was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.
extern "Python": function Cryptography_rand_status() called, but @ffi.def_extern() was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.
```

I'm finding some commonality with Kodi.bin (v.17) but I can't tell if that is qualitative or quantitative yet. I'd appreciate any troubleshooting tips or known bugs :)

Comment: update: i can tie the log growth to Kodi, cross posting this to Kodi.tv forums

Comment: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Manually downloading and installing `python-cryptography` and `python-openssl` from the Ubuntu package repository might be a safer alternative to adding the repository for a future distribution to your sources list.

I achieved this by downloading the appropriate packages from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/python-openssl) and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/python-cryptography), then installing them using `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i python-cryptography_1.7.1-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-openssl_16.2.0-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

**Important:** Read the output of the last command carefully. It threatened to remove a load of packages when I ran it, because dependencies weren't met - I initially tried to install `python-openssl` without `python-cryptography`.

Read more about manually installing packages:
[How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

After a reboot my Unity log file is no longer increasing in size at a rate of 10 MB per second.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I commented the zesty source out after I installed it so no other packages wouldn't update but this is far easier.

Comment: This method is also mentioned on the bug report for this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1636573/comments/11

Comment: The 2 debs are probably. the wrong way around (as seen here https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/447828 )

Answer (score 0):

Found a known bug, need to update `python-openssl`.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1636573, Will report back.

**Edit:** Upgrading python crypto solves the issue :)

What you can do is to install python-cryptography version 1.7.1-2 and python-openssl version 16.2.0-1 from distro Zesty (Ubuntu 17.04). What I did:

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

Add:

```
#Zesty
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty main 
deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty main
```

(For Sweden, you can of course change to your country's repository, first letters after `http://`)

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install python-cryptography=1.7.1-2
```

This will also upgrade python-openssl to latest version

Comment: Unless you're already running Zesty, I wouldn't add Zesty to sources.list. This will cause all kinds of future problems as the entire system will slowly try to upgrade itself to Zesty.