# Huge syslog file

Tags: disk-usage, syslog

My syslog file located at `/var/log` was about 80GB today so I empty it and in a couple of hours it has grown to 30GB already, this is what the log file keeps on writing:

```
Sep 18 19:35:26 media-OptiPlex-3050 gnome-session[1243]: extern "Python": function Cryptography_rand_status() called, but @ffi.def_extern() was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.
Sep 18 19:35:26 media-OptiPlex-3050 gnome-session[1243]: •••••••••extern "Python": function Cryptography_rand_bytes() called, but @ffi.def_extern() was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.
Sep 18 19:35:26 media-OptiPlex-3050 gnome-session[1243]: •••••••••extern "Python": function Cryptography_rand_status() called, but @ffi.def_extern() was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.
Sep 18 19:35:26 media-OptiPlex-3050 gnome-session[1243]: extern •••••••••"Python": function Cryptography_rand_bytes() called, but @ffi.def_extern() was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.•••••••••
```

Comment: What have you changed on your system?

Comment: I had the same issue with a script i started somehow that was outputting > gnome-session[1651]: to accept, n otherwise: rapidly. I killed 1651 trough top, and it broke the system so i had to restart, BUT, at least it stopped it from filling my syslog file. You can try killing 1243 if you dont care about that, would wait for another answer tough

Comment: See https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/447828

Comment: @RoVo good one ;-) I found this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pyopenssl/+bug/1636573 and it is a link that is linked to in yours

Comment: [Related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887220/cache-upstart-unity7-log-growing-to-consume-the-entire-free-disk-space-python)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is a mismatch between python cryptography and the infamous bug that was in openSSL.  There is a workaround by downloading and force-updating both to a version that match both.

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/python-cryptography_1.7.1-2_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/python-openssl_16.2.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-openssl_16.2.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-cryptography_1.7.1-2_amd64.deb
```

This [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pyopenssl/+bug/1636573) has been solved in newer releases.